# XAMPP versus individual installation

Tags: xampp, stack, lamp

I'd want to know the difference between XAMPP installation against installing the Apache, MySQL and PHP on Linux.  A customized CMS that we are trying to implement is working fine with XAMPP, but isn't working on a Linux machine (where Apache, php and mysql were installed individually.  We have verified that php files work, but CMS isnt working').

Is/are there any modules/files that XAMPP provides that is missing in individual installation?

Appreciate any inputs on this issue.

Comment: configs are different

Answer (score 0):

Check PHP versions, that is probably the first thing to verify. Then if the php version is the same you can look at the config files (check directories/paths) within your application's code. You can also take a look at php.ini (php's conf file) & httpd.conf (apache's conf file -though it can have multiple conf files)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if all the plugins in the CMS are compactable with the PHP version. Also, make Apache look for index.php first rather than index.html in

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

If it is in Wordpress enable the Debug mode in the wp-config.php file and check for errors.

This will give you an idea of what went wrong. You can take it from there.